# Syntax Error: Expected the optional content group list, but wasn't able to find it, or > it isn't an Array

Tags: pdftex

I am getting the following error when I run pdflatex:

```
Syntax Error: Expected the optional content group list, but wasn't able to find it, or
it isn't an Array
```

It SEEMS to build correctly, but I am just trying to figure out why this is happening. The following code triggers the problem.

```
\begin{figure}[hbtp] %[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{figures/illustration.pdf} 
\end{figure}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Here is the additional information that was requested:

output of pdftex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4535 (1.40.13) (MiKTeX 2.9)
Copyright (C) 1982 D. E. Knuth, (C) 1996-2012 Han The Thanh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.

And here is a link to the pdf causing the issues: https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6819494_1990813_6559556

**EDIT**

Well, I've learned a bit more. Although I don't know what the problem is exactly with the pdf, it IS a problem with the pdf. I created it using the [dopdf](http://www.dopdf.com/) printer. I created the same one using [cutepdf](http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/Writer.asp), and pdflatex compiled without any errors.

On a somewhat-related note: if anyone has recommendations on a nice, free pdf printer, let me know! I've used dopdf for awhile, which seems to work just fine for regular pdf viewing. I think that cutepdf will become what I use for tex documents from now on, unless people have other solutions.

And if anyone is able to identify exactly WHY the dopdf version isn't working, please share!

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a complete example that reproduces the problem. Nothing appears to be wrong with the fragment you have provided.

Comment: You are using `\label` without `\caption` before, which can lead to an incorrect reference. Besides that, it looks like a pdf previewer or printing error message. Check if compiling causes it, or viewing/printing.

Answer (score 3):

The error message probably comes from the library (`xpdf` or `poppler`) that pdfTeX uses to read and embed PDF files. Either `illustration.pdf` is indeed broken or the library has a bug or does not support this kind of PDF files. For further analysis the output of

```
pdftex --version
```

and the file `figures/illustration.pdf` would be useful.

**Edit**

File `illustration.pdf` is faulty, its reformatted `/Catalog` object:

```
1 0 obj
<< 
  /Type /Catalog
  /Pages 2 0 R
  /PageLayout /OneColumn
  /PageMode /UseNone
  /OCProperties << 
    /D << 
      /Order []
      /AS [
        << 
          /Event /View
          /Category [/View ]
        >>
        << 
          /Event /Print
          /Category [/Print ]
        >>
        << 
          /Event /Export
          /Category [/Export ]
        >>
      ]
    >>
  >>
>>
endobj
```

The PDF specification says about `OCProperties`:

> The optional `OCProperties` entry in the document catalog (see Section 3.6.1,
>   "Document Catalog") holds the optional content properties dictionary, which
>   contains a list of all the optional content groups in the document,
>   […]

The list is specified in key `/OCGs`:

> Key: OCGs
>   Type: array
>   Value: (Required) An array of indirect references to all the optional
>   content groups in the document (see Section 4.10.1, "Optional Content Groups"),
>   any order. Every optional content group must be included in this array.

The required key `/OCGs` is indeed missing and the error message of MiKTeX's
pdfTeX is correct.

The file was created by (`/Producer` entry in the catalog):

```
doPDF Ver 7.2 Build 361 (Windows 7 Business Edition (SP 1) - Version: 6.1.7601 (x64))
```

I have not found that optional content groups are used in `illustration.pdf`. Thus the
bug is probably that the `/OCProperties` key should have been removed if there are no
optional content groups. Also MiKTeX's pdfTeX runs without error, if `/OCProperties` is
changed (e.g. in /qCProperties).

IMHO the error message is correct, but it can be ignored, because optional content
groups are not used anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I modified my original post to include the pdf in question as well as the version of pdftex.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the extension of the file, it gets automatically added by pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.55]{figures/illustration} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: True, but does not seem to address the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This image works fine with `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)`, so I suspect a bug in the pdfTeX of MikTeX. Please file a bug there.
[Googling the error message](https://www.google.de/search?hl=de&q=Expected%20the%20optional%20content%20group%20list&sei=_mYhUI-zCNDitQa5w4CwDw&gbv=2#hl=de&safe=off&gbv=2&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22Expected%20the%20optional%20content%20group%20list%22&oq=%22Expected%20the%20optional%20content%20group%20list%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.27475.28667.0.29095.2.2.0.0.0.0.115.197.1j1.2.0...0.0...1c.Xgw5DGgstLU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=794d118f1aba0a47&biw=1422&bih=994) suggests a bug in older versions of poppler.